# Use React-window in React Realtime Chat App

Tags: reactjs, chat, react-window

My React real time chat app (app look like facebook - messenger facebook.com/messages).
`MessageItem` can be video, sticker, mention, text, emoji.
I want use `react-window` lib to handle scrolling `messengerList` but I not sure `react-window` good for scrolling messenger chat app, because when user scroll up, `messengerList` will append new message into list (like facebook messenger).

Can you tell me when use `react-window` and my chat app should use `react-window` or not ?

Thank for your help.